# tensorflow distributed training w/ estimator + experiment framework

Tags: tensorflow

Hi I have a wield situation when trying to use estimator + experiment class for distributed training.

Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/protoget/2cf2b530bc300f209473374cf02ad829

This is a simple case that uses

1. DNNClassifier from TF official tutorial
2. Experiment framework
3. 1 worker and 1 ps on the same host with different ports.

What happens is

1) when I start ps job, it looks good:

```
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:200] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job ps -> {0 -> localhost:9000}
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:200] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> 127.0.0.1:9001}
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:221] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:9000
```

2) when I start worker job, the job silently exits, leaving no log at all.

Eagerly seeking help.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and I finally get the solution.

The problem is in `config._environment`

```
config = {"cluster": {'ps':     ['127.0.0.1:9000'],
                      'worker': ['127.0.0.1:9001']}}

if args.type == "worker":
    config["task"] = {'type': 'worker', 'index': 0}
else:
    config["task"] = {'type': 'ps', 'index': 0}

os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps(config)

config = run_config.RunConfig()

config._environment = run_config.Environment.CLOUD
```

Set config._environment as `Environment.CLOUD`.

Then you can have distributed training system.

I hope it makes you happy :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, it's due to some internal tensorflow code I guess, I've opened a question on SO already for this: [TensorFlow: minimalist program fails on distributed mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076035/tensorflow-minimalist-program-fails-on-distributed-mode).

I also opened a pull request: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8796.

There are two options to solve your issue. As this is due to your `ClusterSpec` having implicit `local` environment, you could try set another one (either `google` or `cloud`), but I cannot assure you that the rest of your work won't be impacted. So I prefered to have a glance at the code and try fix it myself for local mode, which is why I explain bellow.

You'll see explanations of why it fails in those posts more precisely, the fact is Google has been pretty silent so far so what I did is that I patched their source code (in `tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py`):

```
# Start the server, if needed. It's important to start the server before
# we (optionally) sleep for the case where no device_filters are set.
# Otherwise, the servers will wait to connect to each other before starting
# to train. We might as well start as soon as we can.
config = self._estimator.config
if (config.environment != run_config.Environment.LOCAL and
   config.environment != run_config.Environment.GOOGLE and
   config.cluster_spec and config.master):
 self._start_server()
```

(this part prevents server from starting in local mode, which is yours if you set none in your cluster spec, so you should simply comment `config.environment != run_config.Environment.LOCAL and` and that should work).