# TensorFlow: minimalist program fails on distributed mode

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wrote a very simple program that runs just fine without distribution but hangs on `CheckpointSaverHook` in distributed mode (everything on my localhost though!). I've seen there's been a few questions about hanging in distributed mode, but none seem to match my question.

Here's the script (made to toy with the new layers API):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import learn_runner
from tensorflow.contrib import layers

DATA_SIZE=10
DIMENSION=5
FEATURES='features'

def generate_input_fn():
    def _input_fn():
        mid = int(DATA_SIZE/2)

        data = np.array([np.ones(DIMENSION) if x < mid else -np.ones(DIMENSION) for x in range(DATA_SIZE)])
        labels = ['0' if x < mid else '1' for x in range(DATA_SIZE)]

        table = tf.contrib.lookup.string_to_index_table_from_tensor(tf.constant(['0', '1']))
        label_tensor = table.lookup(tf.convert_to_tensor(labels, dtype=tf.string))

        return dict(zip([FEATURES], [tf.convert_to_tensor(data, dtype=tf.float32)])), label_tensor
    return _input_fn

def build_estimator(model_dir):
    features = layers.real_valued_column(FEATURES, dimension=DIMENSION)
    return tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
        model_dir=model_dir,
        dnn_feature_columns=[features],
        dnn_hidden_units=[20,20])

def generate_exp_fun():
    def _exp_fun(output_dir):
        return tf.contrib.learn.Experiment(
            build_estimator(output_dir),
            train_input_fn=generate_input_fn(),
            eval_input_fn=generate_input_fn(),
            train_steps=100
        )
    return _exp_fun

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)
    learn_runner.run(generate_exp_fun(), 'job_dir')
```

To test distributed mode, I simply launch it with the environment variable `TF_CONFIG={"cluster": {"ps":["localhost:5040"], "worker":["localhost:5041"]}, "task":{"type":"worker","index":0}, "environment": "local"}` (this is for the worker, the same with `ps` type is used to launch the parameter server.

I use tensorflow-1.0.1 (but had the same behavior with 1.0.0) on windows-64, only CPU. I actually never get any error, it just hang on after `INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.` forever... I've tried to attach VisualStudio C++ debugger to the process but with little success so far, so I can't print a stack for what's happening in the native part.

*P.S.: it's not a problem with `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier` because it fails as well with a simple `tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier`. And as noted in the comments, it's not due to both process running on `localhost`, since it fails also when running on separate VMs.*

**EDIT:** I think there's actually an issue with server launching. It looks like the server is not launched when you're in local mode (no matter if distributed or not), cf. `tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py l.250-258`:

```
# Start the server, if needed. It's important to start the server before
# we (optionally) sleep for the case where no device_filters are set.
# Otherwise, the servers will wait to connect to each other before starting
# to train. We might as well start as soon as we can.
config = self._estimator.config
if (config.environment != run_config.Environment.LOCAL and
    config.environment != run_config.Environment.GOOGLE and
    config.cluster_spec and config.master):
  self._start_server()
```

This will prevent the server from being started in local mode for the workers... Anyone has an idea if it's a bug or there's something I'm missing?

Comment: Note that if I run the same script inside two seperate VMs they also fail to run it... So it's not due to both living on localhost.

Comment: Opened a github issue on TensorFlow repository: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this has been answered in: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8796. Finally, one should use `CLOUD` for any distributed operation.